# Check Radio Button By Default In Zend Form Not Working

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I'm using the following code to make a radio button group of two radios in zend form. I want to check first of them by default on but this is code is  not working for that. 
Any help will be appreciated. My code is

```
$is_private = new Zend_Form_Element('is_private', array(
                'elemName'=>'is_private',
                'type' =>'radio',
                'multiOptions' => array('Y'=>'&nbsp;Yes&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;', 'N'=>'&nbsp;No'),
                'labelClass'=>'inline',
                'spanClass'=>'lbl',
                            'setValue'=> 'Y',
                            'checked'=>'checked',
                'decorators' => array($radiodecorator),
        ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$is_private=new Zend_Form_Element_radio('is_private', array(
    'required'   => true,
     'elemName'=>'is_private',
     'type' =>'radio', // not needed
    'multiOptions' => array(
        'yes' => 'yes',
        'no' => 'no'
    ),
    'value' => 'yes' // default value
));
```

Comment: well, certainly works for me, ! are you getting any error? what version of zf you are using ?